# fg command vs SIGCONT

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, operating-system

I am trying to implement a shell in C. Currently, I am trying to handle a STOP signal (Ctrl+Z). While testing this, I found the following issue.

[image]

As shown in the underlined portion, the SIGCONT does not restart the process like it is supposed to, but the fg command does. (The pid is correct I have checked many times)

Comment: Might be good to format this to include a direct and specific question rather than letting it just be implied.